# Telegraf, trigger at start and not interval?

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

Hello i am currently trying to parse a folder of many csv Files(ca. 3GB) into influxdb.
On the influxdata [blog](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/how-to-write-points-from-csv-to-influxdb/) it was suggested, that this would be the fastest way since telegraf is written in go.So:

I can get everything to work and i can parse all csv´s and write them to influxdb.
The Problem is that parsing and writing the files takes a lot of time (old macbook..more than an hour i think) and when the agent interval is smaller than the time it takes to write the data, telegraf-agent will start again to read and write all files at the next interval. So it never finishes and my ram gets packed with all the same parsed data over and over. When i set the interval really high i have to wait one interval before the agent starts. So not an option too.
The question is:

Can telegraf be triggert like a script? So that i just run it one time and not have to wait for one interval to start?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you need has been added since this question was asked. You can now run Telegraf with a `--once` flag.

I can't find it documented anywhere, but the commit is [here](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/commit/4e93b8708555ccbe534f8c781c3b7cbfc9c81bb5#diff-62b6ad581fe3a3059ae8c85ef0f31dde4092bfdecfa7d6857c470bcacaa8cc8b).

It's available in v1.15.0-rc1

Comment: Thank you. I will try it when I need it again.